How does psychiatry judge suicide by military and political leaders?
I've revised How does psychiatry judge suicide by military and political leaders? Would it be on-topic now please? Any recommendations for improvement? 

I’m voting to close this question because it's no longer needed.

The item in question was reopened three hours later.
